# jQuery accessing a div string exploding and comparing

Tags: jquery

I would like to access a div that I have hidden at the bottom of the page. $existing_user is an array and the div is hidden.

```
<div id="existing_user"><?php echo json_encode($existing_user); ?></div>
```

I am then trying to compare the div to a user generated input.

```
<input type='text' name='user_name' id='user_name' />
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var existing_user_string = $('#existing_user').text();
var existing_user_array = explode(",",existing_user_string);

if (jQuery.inArray($('#fruit').val(),existing_user_array) == -1) {
    alert('no way this worked');
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not have an `explode` function. To get the array of users, use `JSON.parse`*:

```
var existing_user_array = JSON.parse( $('#existing_user').text() );

if (jQuery.inArray($('#fruit').val(),existing_user_array) == -1) {
    alert('no way this worked');
}
```

---

**P.S.** Any reason you're not `echo`ing the `json_encode`d array directly into a script?

```
<script>var existing_user_array = <?php echo json_encode($existing_user); ?></script>
```

That way you don't have to go fishing in the DOM for it, and you don't even have to parse the JSON (just be sure to have this script generated before the other script is included on the page, so that the `existing_user_array` is populated before you try using it).

<sub>*`JSON.parse` is not available in IE7 and below. If you have to take this route and have to support those older browsers, be sure to include [Crockford's json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).</sub>

Comment: For some reason when I tried to echo it into the script it was coming up null. dunno why. But when I echo it at the end of the page and try to pull it, it works.

Comment: @noWayhome - Because you were `echo`ing it after you already included your other script. You have to ascertain that the `existing_user_array` is available before you try using it.

Comment: How do I ascertain that the `existing_user_array` is available before I try using it?

Comment: By `echo`ing it before you include the other script.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I thought that I had to put all my jQuery scripts at the top of the page...I moved the ones that I needed to be lower down and used `json_encode` thanks :-)